# how to make sure a developer is working effectively?

Tags: business

Let's say I hire some developer or an artist for a project, and that I pay him hourly. How am I supposed to know how many hours he worked for the content he provides to me ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not specific to game development. You may want to consider looking at the Programmers or Workplace SE sites.